# Next js Strapi - error - TypeError: fetch failed

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:assert" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Comment: What version of node are you running? `node -v`

Comment: I'm using node v18.1.0

Comment: Did you try updating Next.js? It seems this problem was related to versions 12.1.5 and previous.

Comment: not yet, I will do right now...

Comment: im using and getting the same error "next": "^11.1.4",

Comment: @GleicianoSilva Next is on version 12 already. Can you update Next to the latest version. Uninstall the old "next" with `npm uninstall next` and then reinstall `npm install next`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with next 12.3.1 and STRAPI VERSION v4.4.1.
It was due to the strapi was running on node 16 and next was running on 18.
Check your version of next and strapi installation by running

- `node -v`  (in terminal in the root folder of both next and strapi)
  if they are different run
- `nvm install v16`(for the nextjs root)
- `nvm use 16`   (on the nextjs root)

This solved my issue.
(also remember to pass an absolute URL for the fetch)